# How to manage static files on a CDN and business logic on another server in one git repo?

Tags: node.js, git, cdn

I'm building an app on Nodejitsu, which doesn't allow deployment packages of over 30MB. Most of the app is AngularJS, so I can keep all this on a separate server and greatly reduce the package size.

However, it's managed with one git repo, organized like this:

```
app/       <-- node files to deploy to Nodejitsu
config/
test/
package.json 
server.js
public/    <-- static files to deploy to CDN
    img/
    css/
    js/  
docs/      <-- don't want to deploy this anywhere, but still keep in git repo
```

I'm basically looking for a better way to deploy this all. I would like to keep it all in the same git repo, but I need commands to:

1. deploy only `app`, `config`, `test`, `package.json`, and `server.js` with `jitsu deploy`
2. deploy `public` to a CDN (even cooler if I can just publish `img` and two minified JS and CSS files)
3. keep certain directories (like `docs`) in the git repo, but exclude from deployment

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the `public/` directory to [PageCDN](https://pagecdn.com/). It allows selecting a single directory inside a github repo before deploying the repo to the CDN. More details are available in [docs](https://docs.pagecdn.com/quick-start#setting-up-cdn-with-a-github-repo).